# Script returns output in IDLE not when executed at CLI

Tags: python, linux, bash

I have a script that runs a few external commands and returns their values.  I am able to run the script within IDLE just fine, and I get the expected results.

When I execute the script in a Linux shell (Bash), it runs, but with no output.

The exit status is 0.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import array,os,subprocess


def vsdIndex(vmVsd):
   index = subprocess.call(["/root/indeces.sh", vmVsd], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=TRUE).communicate()[0]
   print index
return (firstSerial,lastSerial)

def main():

    vsdArray = []
    vsdProc = subprocess.Popen(["sc vsd show | tail -n +2 | grep -Ev 'iso|ISO|vfd' | awk '{{print $1}}'"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
    while True:
       line = vsdProc.stdout.readline()
       if line != '':
          vsdIndex(line) 
          print "VSD:", line.rstrip()
          print firstSerial
          print lastSerial
       else:
          break
```

If I simplify it, and run without the function, I have the same behaviour:

```
def main():

    vsdArray = []
    vsdProc = subprocess.Popen(["sc vsd show | tail -n +2 | grep -Ev 'iso|ISO|vfd' | awk '{{print $1}}'"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
    while True:
       line = vsdProc.stdout.readline()
       if line != '':
          print "VSD:", line.rstrip()
       else:
          break
```

Comment: you should look up the documentation on `communicate` as it is not  doing what you think it is ... (especially when you access the 0th index of the return) ... that may or maynot have anything at all with your problem...

Answer (score 0):

You need to call your main() function. Here is a common way of doing that automatically when you run on the command line:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```